# Can I split this column containing a mix of tuples/None more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcd')})
df['tuples'] = df.index.map(lambda i:(i,i+1))

# outputs:
#   id  tuples
# 0  a  (0, 1)
# 1  b  (1, 2)
# 2  c  (2, 3)
# 3  d  (3, 4)
```

I can then split the tuples column into two very simply, e.g.

```
df[['x','y']] = pd.DataFrame(df.tuples.tolist())

# outputs:
#   id  tuples  x  y
# 0  a  (0, 1)  0  1
# 1  b  (1, 2)  1  2
# 2  c  (2, 3)  2  3
# 3  d  (3, 4)  3  4
```

This approach also works:

```
df[['x','y']] = df.apply(lambda x:x.tuples,result_type='expand',axis=1)
```

However if my DataFrame is slightly more complex, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcd')})
df['tuples'] = df.index.map(lambda i:(i,i+1) if i%2 else None)

# outputs:
#   id  tuples
# 0  a    None
# 1  b  (1, 2)
# 2  c    None
# 3  d  (3, 4)
```

then the first approach throws "Columns must be same length as key" (of course) because some rows have two values and some have none, and my code anticipates two.

I can use .loc to create single columns, twice.

```
get_rows = df.tuples.notnull() # return rows with tuples

df.loc[get_rows,'x'] = df.tuples.str[0]
df.loc[get_rows,'y'] = df.tuples.str[1]

# outputs:
#   id  tuples    x    y
# 0  a    None  NaN  NaN
# 1  b  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
# 2  c    None  NaN  NaN
# 3  d  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

[Aside: useful how the indexing carries assigns only relevant rows from the right, without having to specify them.]

However, I can't use .loc to create two columns at once, e.g.

```
# This isn't valid use of .loc
df.loc[get_rows,['x','y']] = df.loc[get_rows,'tuples'].map(lambda x:list(x))
```

as it throws the error "shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)".

I also can't use this

```
df[get_rows][['x','y']] = df[get_rows].apply(lambda x:x.tuples,result_type='expand',axis=1)
```

as it throws the usual "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc..."

I can't help thinking I'm missing something.

Comment: not sure but try changing `df[get_rows][['x','y']]` to `df.loc[get_rows, ['x','y']]`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. Yuan's answer shows the right way to think about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**df[get_rows] is a copy**, set value to df[get_rows][['x','y']] **does not** change the underlying data. Just use df[['x','y']] to create now columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcd')})

df['tuples'] = df.index.map(lambda i:(i,i+1) if i%2 else None)

get_rows = df.tuples.notnull()

df[['x','y']] = df[get_rows].apply(lambda x:x.tuples,result_type='expand',axis=1)

print(df)

  id  tuples    x    y
0  a    None  NaN  NaN
1  b  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  c    None  NaN  NaN
3  d  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, Yuan. I sensed there should be a simple fix; I didn't expect it to be so straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way (*comments inline*):

```
c=df.tuples.astype(bool) #similar to df.tuples.notnull()
#create a dataframe by dropping the None and assign index as df.index where c is True
d=pd.DataFrame(df.tuples.dropna().values.tolist(),columns=list('xy'),index=df[c].index)
final=pd.concat([df,d],axis=1) #concat them both
```

---

```
  id  tuples    x    y
0  a    None  NaN  NaN
1  b  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  c    None  NaN  NaN
3  d  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, anky_91. This is a good alternative, but I've marked Yuan's as the answer as it's is closer to the approach I was working with.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick fix:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.tuples.to_dict()).T], 
          axis=1)
```

returns:

```
  id  tuples     0     1
0  a    None  None  None
1  b  (1, 2)     1     2
2  c    None  None  None
3  d  (3, 4)     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
In [862]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [863]: new_columns = ['x', 'y']

In [864]: df.join(df.tuples.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(zip_longest(new_cols, [x] if pd.isnull(x) else list(x))))))
Out[864]: 
  id  tuples    x    y
0  a    None  NaN  NaN
1  b  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  c    None  NaN  NaN
3  d  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

---

Or even simpler:

```
In [876]: f = lambda x: [x] * len(new_cols) if pd.isnull(x) else list(x)

In [877]: df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.tuples.apply(f).tolist(), columns=new_cols))
Out[877]: 
  id  tuples    x    y
0  a    None  NaN  NaN
1  b  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  c    None  NaN  NaN
3  d  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```